# Configuring network access in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, visual-studio-express

I am creating a small windows forms application to allow me to type in a computer name or IP address, and then click various buttons that would call up a command window and perform various tasks such as pinging, nslookup, etc.

The problem I am having is that when I try this, the ping function for example acts as though I have no network connectivity ("general failure"). If i manually run a command prompt and run a ping it works fine. Do I have to somehow allow network access for my program? If so, how would I go about this? I use Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

Thanks

(Note: The string "inputText" is the string that gets captured from the text box on my GUI

```
//pings the computer or IP address received in the input box
    private void buttonPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool noInput = String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText);

        //refuses input if text box is empty
        if (noInput == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a computer name or IP address in the text box.");
        }
        else
        {
            //starts an instance of the command prompt, and passes the string to the console
            String strCmdPing = String.Format("ping {0} -t", inputText);
            Process.Start("CMD", "/c" + strCmdPing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the parameter you're passing to `CMD`

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could simply do something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostic;

protected void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtIPAddress.Text))
          throw new ArgumentNullException();

     string command = @"ping " + txtIPAddress.Text;
     Process.Start("CMD.exe", command);
}
```

That is a simple primitive example, but without code or more information this would be the basic assumption I believe you mean.